# when I built my app in xcode,there is an error:/bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bash, shell

the error information:

> /Users/baymac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Accelerometer_Nodes-ccicmwcpsbuvnnfllupzhsbpxwrr/Build/Intermediates/Accelerometer
>   Nodes.build/Debug-iphoneos/Accelerometer
>   Nodes.build/Script-2C82A787FAD9698819CAEFB4.sh:
>   /Users/baymac/Documents/patrick lab/ios
>   project/DeviceToPhone/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods/Pods-frameworks.sh: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not
>   permitted Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 126

I have tried pods install or chmod,they are useless,it would be so nice if any one can help me!!

Comment: pod not installed properly. or make sure you are opening the workspace file not xcodeproject file.

Comment: I open the xcodeproject file indeed,and my classmate told not to install pod because we need old files in pod.If I install it again,the pod will be updated and those file needed may be revised....can you help me ???

Comment: If you could add a copy of your `Podfile` to your question, that may help. That said: the first thing I do whenever I have an issue with CocoaPods is run pod deintegrate followed by pod install. That may be worth giving a try. You will need to install it first to use it: github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

Comment: I tried and those files needed in old pod are missing,so......it seems worse now.......maybe I need to reload app now..

Comment: I have the same issue but I have several targets on the project workspace and I cannot remove the workspace, did you find any solution for this situation?

Answer (score 16):

I faced same issue.

Reason: If you download project from internet, executable .sh files will be quarantined, and system doesn't allow them to execute.

Cure: You should remove extended attributes to make these executables work.

In terminal

```
xattr -rc directory_where_executables_located
```

this will recursively remove extended attributes from files in directory_where_executables_located

Comment: This saved my day ... thanks

Answer (score 15):

if install pods is useless,maybe you can find the path of the file with error,for example,my path is /Users/baymac/Documents/patrick lab/ios project/DeviceToPhone/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-frameworks.sh

then you can use this instruct:
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine+ your path，for example:

xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Users/baymac/Documents/patrick lab/ios project/DeviceToPhone/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-frameworks.sh

make sure your path is right.

and my problem is fixed!

Comment: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine        :((

Answer (score 12):

Try to remove .xcworkspace and Podfile.lock files also remove folder Pod

then open terminal
type cd put path of your project root folder press enter
type pod install or pod update press enter

Answer (score 8):

For me what fixed it was removing

```
ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = YES;
```

from project.pbxproj. It was added as a suggested setting by XCode. It seems to be incompatible with Capacitor which i'm using to build my app.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answer of [mcarriere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77180445/11781388)

> For me what fixed it was removing
>
> ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = YES;
> from project.pbxproj. It was added as a suggested setting by XCode. It seems to >be incompatible with Capacitor which i'm using to build my app.

I just changed the `ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = NO` and it worked.